# harmonic function invariant under a rotation

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Suppose that $u$ is a harmonic function on the unit disk such that $u(e^{2\pi i/9}z)=u(z)$ for all $z$. Prove that $u$ has a harmonic conjugate $v$ such that $v(e^{2\pi i/9}z)=v(z)$ for all $z$.

I have no idea what to do. Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Can we use the fact that $u + vi$ is complex differentiable?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, we can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach:

Define $f(z) = u(z) + iv(z)$, where $v$ is some harmonic conjugate of $u$.  Let $\alpha = e^{2 \pi i /9}$
Since $g(z) = \alpha z$ is an analytic function, the composition $f(g(z)) = f(\alpha z)$ must be analytic. From there, we note that
$$
f(\alpha z) - f(z) = [u(\alpha z) - u(z)] + i[v(\alpha z) - v(z)] = i [v(\alpha z) - v(z)]
$$
Since $f(\alpha z) - f(z)$ is the difference of analytic functions, it is analytic.
So, $v(\alpha z) - v(z)$ is a harmonic conjugate to $0$, which means that $v(\alpha z) - v(z)$ must be constant (verify this).  Since $v(\alpha z) - v(z)$ is defined over the entire unit disk (which includes the point $z = 0$), we may state that for all $z$, we have
$$
v(\alpha z) - v(z) = v(\alpha \cdot 0) - v(0) = v(0) - v(0) = 0
$$
We conclude that any harmonic conjugate $v$ of $u$ satisfies $v(\alpha z) = (z)$ for all $z$ in the disk.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks!!!!